# what complier do when overloads operators in a class?

Tags: c++, class, overloading

Take "+" as an example.when overloading operator+ in a class:

```
class obj{
    public:
    int data;
    obj(){data=1;}
    int operator+(const obj b){
        return data+b.data;  //->this is ok when we "adding" two obj.
    }
};
```

but when i do the same "overload" outside the class,like:

```
int operator+(const obj x){
        return x;}// this is not okey when "adding" a number and a obj
```

it seems that when we overloading operator"+" in class,the complier "helps" us to pass a "class" parameter to make that overloading works.

So now that i wonder whether complier do some work which is implicit to programmer or there is some implicit function are announced in a class.

By a way,i also want to know whether the statement below is ture or not.

Statement:"We should always pass the same parameter number,when we overloading an opertor,as an opertor needs(when we use that operator alone)to parameter list.

Comment: perhaps you are looking for `int operator+(int a, const obj b) {}`?

Comment: no, i know how to makes it works, i am curious about why complier "pass" a parameter automatic when overloading in a class which is contradict to what it do when overlording outside a class.

Comment: In methods, the compiler passes a *hidden* `this` parameter which is a pointer to the current object (the object on which the method is called).

Comment: These are two different operators you are overloading. The first one overloads the binary addition operator, the second one overloads the unary plus operator

Comment: It's the same as how you can write `obj(){data=1;}` instead of `obj(obj &o) {o.data=1;}`. How does it know which obj has the right data field? SpoooOOOooookyyy!

Comment: i think this is easy to understand and this is not the point.Becuasue when you “delte” the data ,instead of"return data+b.date" in a class,by taking no advantage of"date",like "return b.data",it also works.The main point is the incohernet of what complier do between inside  and outside the class.

Comment: inspired by this thought,i have tried another operator method like this:```obj(obj a,obj b){return a.data+b.data}``` inside and outside a class.unexpectly,it successful complied when i defined the overload inside when,in contrast, failed to complie when defining outside the class.

Comment: so in a conclusion,it's just as what Serge Ballesta said,the complier "always"pass a parameter when we overload inside a class and do nothing otherwise which meet the principle of coherence.